# i try to select some rows in tables - and get error

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have table that i map her with numbers.

i need to see rows from 13 to 20

i try this:

```
select  Fname,Lname,rollet,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY rollet) AS RowID
from BackUp2 
where RowID between 13 and 20
```

and i get this error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'RowID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'RowID'.
```

what i can do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *
from ( select 
  Fname,Lname,rollet,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY rollet) AS RowID
from BackUp2 ) xx

where xx.RowID between 13 and 20
```

Comment: than'k for the help, but i get error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Sorry-Forgot the inner SELECT statement, I've added it